# Javafx 2 Javascript ReferenceError

Tags: java, javascript, javafx-2

I am following the tutorial provided for Javafx 2 from this page :

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm

My fxml code is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?language javascript?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane gridLinesVisible="false" hgap="10.0" vgap="10.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <fx:script>
    function handleSubmit() {
        actionTarget.setText("Calling the Javascript");
    }
  </fx:script>
  <children>
    <Text text="Welcome" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.rowSpan="1" />
    <Label text="Username" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <Label text="Password" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <PasswordField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
    <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
      <children>
        <Button onAction="handleSubmit(event);" text="Sign In" />
      </children>
    </HBox>
    <Text fx:id="actionTarget" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
  </children>
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="25.0" left="25.0" right="25.0" top="25.0" />
  </padding>
</GridPane>
```

But whenever i click the button I get the error :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "handleSubmit" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "handleSubmit" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong in the code ?
I am using Oracle Java 8 JRE on Xubuntu

Comment: I tried it with JDK 7 on Ubuntu 13.04 and works, so this might be a JDK 8 bug.

Comment: Yeah I switched to JDK 7 and it worked. 
Write it as an answer so i can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it with JDK 7 on Ubuntu 13.04 and works well, so this might be a JDK 8 bug. It is somehow related to the javascript engine `Nashorn` which is included in JDK 8 (JDK 7 is using `Mozilla Rhino`), I think [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/nashorn-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg00822.html) mail mentions the same problem.